# Ubuntu 13.04 installation fail on ASUS S551LB (Hybrid Graphics)

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, graphics, asus, nvidia-optimus

I've just purchased a new ASUS S551LB. It comes with an i7 4500U and NVidia Geforce 740M, with the NVidia Optimus feature (hybrid graphics). The full specification can be found at [ASUS VivoBook S551LB](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S551LB/)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 and failing badly. During the installation it seems fine, until it we restart the laptop and try to boot it for the first time. The error message says:

```
 8.679154] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:04:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x108120a1
 8.679179] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
15.030164] mei 0000:00:16.0: init hw failure.
15.030230] mei 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed.
```

After I **force** shutdown the laptop and boot it for the second time, I do not see the message again - but just a blank screen. I'm quite lost in the dark on where to start debugging. I've done hairpulling lots of google-ing without finding any result. Any help on how I can successfully install Ubuntu 13.04 is very much appreciated.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Have your tried installing it again. or you can do one thing: While booting from the CD/DVD try once `Use Ubuntu` option, and check whether it works fine.

Comment: Please don't use Nouveau for Optimus. You may be more successful if you try the latest Nvidia proprietary drivers together with Bumblebee. Install the driver in the "Additional Drivers" application and see this for Bumblebee: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I've repeated installing it 3 times. Each time from a bootable USB, and at each time I re-burn the ISO to the USB. It all gave the same result, @SauravKumar

Comment: @gertvdijk, Yes I've been looking at this Bumblebee project. But from what I see is that I will have to install it once I am loaded in Ubuntu -- but how do I get to install it before the first boot? and is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: @HaikalPribadi Oh, sorry, forgot that part. Try starting with a kernel parameter `nouveau.blacklist=1`. How do you do that? Well, see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/38834/88802 (but add the blacklist parameter rather than the Q&A there)

Comment: @gertvdijk Thank you for the advice. Will try it later at home. May I ask, at which line do I include the parameter? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @HaikalPribadi It *does* matter. Same line as in the Q&A I linked - the one with the kernel specified (`vmlinuz`).

Comment: I gave it a shot. But it did not work. An error appeared:
'[   9.336630] nouveau: 1 invalid for parameter blacklist'
'[  15.864797] mei 0000:00:16.0: init hw failure.'
'[  15.864906] mei 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed.'

Do you know what I should do from this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10443/discussion-between-haikal-pribadi-and-gertvdijk)

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try blacklisting the `mei` module, that one is known to cause (re)boot failures. (Likely you won't need that one anyway.)

Add the following line to the end of your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
blacklist mei
```

Or if you can't get to the system, then blacklist it on boot by adding the kernel parameter

```
modprobe.blacklist=mei
```

at GRUB. (If you don't know how to add kernel parameters at boot, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/221281))

Also you may try updating your BIOS.