# Unknown chipset and kvm: disabled by bios

Tags: 13.04

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed. Whenever I boot Ubuntu, I see a message during booting:

```
[    9.035335] nouveau E [  DEVICE] [0000:01:00.0] Unknown chipset, 0x108120a1
[    9.035377] nouveau E [  DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22 
[    9.035388] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.037022] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.038022] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.042021] kvm: disabled by bios
```

What does this mean and what do I do about it?

Comment: Above answer limits to the kvm messages alone. I believe that the nouveau E messages are related to the graphics card. Considering the messages in
http://askubuntu.com/questions/340566/ubuntu-13-04-installation-fail-on-asus-s551lb-hybrid-graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means that virtualisation support is disabled in the motherboard's firmware. It's often disabled by default.

Depending on what your motherboard is and what firmware version you're running, you will likely be able to find the option in the BIOS and turn it on.

If you're not running virtual machines, you don't really need to worry about it.